# Running one function after another function finish

Tags: javascript, html

It looks like they're trying to do it at the same time. It works when a timeout is set but that doesn't guarantee it will always work.

Is there another way to make sure the first function is ran first and then the second function is rendered?

The 2 functions are `async` and are not depended on each other but they just happened that it cannot be rendered at the same time.

Comment: we are going to need more details.  Please [edit] your question to include an [mcve]

Comment: i updated some code

Comment: As you can see, there are syntax errors in the code you provided, please fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Check if they are async functions or not.

If they are, encapsulate them in an async function and use await on the first.

```
let diplay_all_charts = async function () {
  await DisplayChart();
  DisplayChart2();
};
display_all_charts();
```

Comment: Hey the 2 functions are async themselves but they dont depend on each other.

Comment: this way doesnt seem to work for me

Answer (score 0):

Regular functions execute one after another, unless they are async. With async functions you'll need call your second function from within your first functions,aka as a callback.

Comment: the 2 functions does not depend on each other but they just happened that it cannot be launched at the same time

Answer (score 0):

- You aren't added the code of the second function but i guess that you created 2 functions `DisplayChart`, `DisplayChart2` which will work at the same time - by default fetching data takes some of time to finish so you can't call `DisplayChart` first then `DisplayChart2` and expect that they will work after each other but from your code you almost there you can use promise to call first function then call the second function from the returned promise of the first

**Example**

```
launchData().then(response => response.data)
      .then(data => {
          const tr = document.createElement("tr");
          const text = document.createElement("td");
          text.innerHTML = Object.keys(data);
          const subtext = document.createElement("td");
          subtext.innerHTML = Object.keys(data).name;
         // Call the second function in here
         launchData2().then(resp => resp.data)
      .then(data => { //your code here })
  })
```